# Doubt: Can I use Nikkor 50mm f1.8G with Nikon D5500?

Tags: cropped-sensor, 50mm

I am new to photography and I am getting a good deal to buy Nikkor 50mm f1.8G lens.

My question is whether I can use Nikkor 50mm f1.8G lens with my crop frame camera Nikon D5500 or not?

My initial guess was that I can definitely use it but on this [link](http://store.mynikonlife.com.au/af-s-50mm-f1-8g), I see a heading '**Fast, f/1.8 compact FX-format prime (fixed focal length) lens**'

As the heading says 'FX-format', does it mean that I can use this lens only with full frame camera?

Please let me know this as I am confused. I appreciate your time and feedback :)

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any FX format Nikon lens on a DX format Nikon camera. On your D5500 the smaller sensor means it will only capture roughly the middle half of the light circle projected by the lens. This is what is referred to as the *crop factor*. Since your Nikon D5500 has a crop factor of 1.5X, the 50mm FX lens will give the same *angle of view* as a 75mm FX lens would on an FX camera. Keep in mind that a 50mm DX lens would also give the same field of view on your D5500: that of a 75mm FX lens on an FX camera.

Comment: If you feel the answer adequately answers the question, feel free to select it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a full-frame (FX) lens with a cropped sensor body.  You can't use a DX lens on a full frame body without vignetting.

With your camera you need to use AF-S lenses with focus motors built into the lens.  This is one of those lenses, so you'll be fine.